# Does an inequality between first-order Taylor approximations imply the same for the functions?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Assume that $f$ and $h$ are functions from $\mathbf{R}^n$ to $\mathbf{R}^1$ and continuously differentiable. Also assume that $f(z)=h(z)$ at some point $z \in \mathbf{R}^n$.

Could we then show that $f(z+v) \le h(z+v)$ whenever $\nabla f(z)^Tv < \nabla h(z)^Tv$ for all $v$ sufficiently close to 0?

I would like to find $\delta > 0$ such that if $\|v\| < \delta$ and $\nabla f(z)^Tv < \nabla h(z)^Tv$, then $f(z+v) \le h(z+v)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in general there is no $\delta>0$ that works for all directions. Counterexample in two dimensions: $$f(x,y)=x^2 , \quad h(x,y)=y$$
with $z= (0,0)$.

Consider vectors $v$ of the form $(\epsilon, \epsilon^2/2)$, where $\epsilon>0$ can be arbitrarily small. Then $f(z+v)>h(z+v)$ even though $\nabla f(z)^Tv < \nabla h(z)^T v$.